# Getting the object from a Dictionary<string,object> that is within a List<T>

Tags: .net, list

I have a `List<T>` that contains, among other things, a `Dictionary<string,object>` called **Fields**. Given a value for the `string` what is the best method of getting the object from the Dictionary?

This is what I've tried so far but it doesn't seem to use the value of the field with a string of "Classification"

```
public static bool CompareClassificationToPopular(List<ClassificationModel> completeClassifications, List<ClassificationModel> popularClassifications)
{
    bool result = true;

    foreach (var popular in popularClassifications)
    {
        var complete = complateClassifications.FirstOrDefault(cc => cc.Fields["Classification"] == popular.Fields["Classification"]);
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: The dictionary's `Value` stores objects and you use `obj1==obj2` to link both. That will just compare references, so if both are the same reference which doesn't seem to be the case. Try to replace `==` with `Equals` and see if it works.

Comment: "I have a List<T> that contains, among other things" Do you mean you've created a class that inherits from `List<T>` and which has a`Dictionary<string,object> Fields` property?

Comment: @vc74: if you look at the code you see that he _has_ some `List<ClassificationModel>` and each `ClassificationModel` has a property(or field) `Fields` which is a `Dictionary<string, Object>`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks, so 2 lists of `ClassificationModel`, each `ClassificationModel` having a `Dictionary<string, object>`, potentially making many dictionaries. Hard to tell which dictionary `the Dictionary` refers to...

Comment: @vc74: according to OP's code the first matching value for the key `Classification`

Comment: Within the fields property I have up to 6 items, one of which has a key of 'Classification'. I need to match this value from completeClassifications with the equivalent value of the key 'Classification' in fields from popularClassifications.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that gives me what I need by casting the Fields item to a string.

```
var complete = completeClassifications.FirstOrDefault(cc => (string)cc.Fields["Classification"] == (string)popular.Fields["Classification"]);
```